# Windows-10 bat script to write multi-lines string into file with single echo command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a bat script that receives a parameter with a JSON string like the following (simplified example):

```
[{a:123,b,456} ,
 {a:111,b:222} ,
 ...
 {a:999,b:888}
]
```

I want to echo this string into a file while keeping the multi-lines structure. Unfortunately, extensive googling did not help so far.

I should add that since the string may contain hundreds of such lines, the use of `echo >...echo >>...echo >>`  is out of the question.

**UPDATE**: Background...

I'm developing a Web application that functions fully within a local machine with no Web server of any kind (to be more specific, the only things that are used from the Web network are Bootstrap, Font Awesome and a Web service that receives GPS coordinates and returns details about the location (like country, city, etc.).

This application needs the ability of manipulating local files and folders, actions that are not accessible to JavaScript (and, I prefer to keep this application without the need of installation of any software).

In order to enable file manipulations, I'm creating a protocol handler `MyPRotocol` (much the same Zoom does) who will invoke the batch file and perform a number of different actions based on the input(s).

For instance, there are situations where the application needs to save a JSON file into a specific and KNOWN subfolder. In such scenario, the Web application would use this new protocol to invoke the batch file (with the applicable parameters) who will perform the task as guided by the received parameters.

Two last points:

1. I'm walking on uncharted territory since this is the first time I'm doing this type of work (e.g. my use of DOS commands is limited to just that, *commands*, and I have quite poor knowledge of scripting in that environment.
2. I'm aware of the potential hazards involved in using custom protocols the way I do, but since this application is fully local, I don't think there is any real exposure to those hazards.

Hope these lines make things clearer.

Comment: how does your batch script receive a multi-line string?

Comment: Thank you @Stephan for addressing this question. The answer is quite long so I added some background to the original question.

Comment: Accordingly to your UPDATE explanation, you have **NOT** a "bat script that receives a multi-line parameter" yet...  **`:/`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... I doubt you have a bat script that receives in a parameter a multi-lines string... (where is the code?)

However, if you could assign such multi-lines string to a variable, you can show it with a single `echo` command this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ^"multiLine=[{a:123,b,456} ,^

 {a:111,b:222} ,^

 {a:555,b:555} ,^

 {a:999,b:888}^

]^"

echo Standard expansion, don't works:
echo %multiLine%

echo/
echo Delayed expansion, DO work^^!:
echo !multiLine!

echo/
echo You can also process the lines with a FOR / command:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!multiLine!") do echo %%a
```

Comment: Thank you Aacini for your response. I added some background to the question explaining the need and planned mechanism (hoping my **theory** is doable).

Comment: Hi again, if I need to write the JSON into a file, the for loop implies using ">" once and ">>" the number of lines minus 1. As stated in my initial post, such approach is quite problematic when dealing with hundreds of records.

Comment: No. Just do this: `(for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!multiLine!") do echo %%a) > outputFile.txt`  Don't matters the number of lines...

Comment: Do you know that a Batch (environment) variable could contain a maximum of 8192 characters? That is all for your "hundreds of records"...

Comment: Interesting... Please check this link: https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/tsleft.web+WinBatch/FAQs~-~Frequently~Asked~Questions+Limitations~-~Maximum~Amounts~.txt. According to this, there is no such limit for variables (actually, the limit is MBs) BUT it would appear that passing a big chunk of characters to a script still displays a limit for my needs. If that is the case (and I'd appreciate your feedback) I'll need to create two protocols where one would activate a compiled program (like C++ or C# for example). Waiting for your feedback and a BIG THANKs to you.

Comment: Your link is about **webbatch.exe** that is a product I don't know. A **Batch File** (text file with .bat extension) as used in this and many other sites, is a standard file for Windows OS that is processed via **cmd.exe** Windows command processor. In such .bat file, the variables can have a maximum of 8192 characters each...

Comment: Hi, I just posted another question and thought you might have the answer(s) for it. The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050634/windows-10-custom-protocol-to-run-a-batch-file-from-javascript-including-param?noredirect=1#comment135831614_77050634. Thanks.